Weird Hall signals on a BLDC motor
I am developing a BLDC motor controller. I have several BLDC motors and they all have similar Hall signals, but two of them have a difference in the Hall signals. They have a small pulse at the start and end of the actual hall signal pulse. Since I have this in two motors, I doubt that it is due to issue in the motor. Why are the Hall signals different?

This extra pulses appear even when rotated by hand or by controller.
The back EMF, shown in green, also is not a proper sine wave; it has the spikes as shown in this image.
This is how the they are all connected

Hall sensor tester is just connected to provide power to the motor's Hall sensors and pull up resistors to the motor's Hall sensors. This works perfectly with all other motors.

What happens if you spin the motor with something else (e.g: by hand / drill)... You should get a perfect sine wave on the three phases, and you can eliminate any electrically induced noise from the hall effect sensors (i.e: do these edges go away?)

The extra pulses on the hall signals are present when rotated by hand or by controller. In the attached image in question, I have rotated the motor by hand.

Is the motor connected to anything other than the scope in that trace? I'd be very surprised to see a phase of a BLDC motor that is spun by hand look like that.

It was connected to a motor tester. this was to provide power and pull up resistor for the motor's hall sensors.

Please can you run it again, with the three motor phases disconnected? Are you confident that the "tester" isn't affecting the hall effect outputs?

The phase wires are disconnected. only the hall sensor wires are connected to tester. and I have used that tester to test other motors and they work without any issue.

Thanks for confirming. Where are you sourcing the phase ground/reference from? (center point of 3x resistors, one to each phase?) ... please consider editing your question with these extra details.

Thanks for the reply. I have edited the question with these extra details.
